# Problems with dotproject date outpu

Tags: php

I'm transalting system and i just got in trouble. Ive got this date: Fri Oct 3 2014 2:30pm . Script of her would be `date($CONFIG["date_format"], $value)` and that date_format is D M j Y g:ia. I don't know how to translate these english days and months Fri Oct i tried using this script:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, '$AppUI->user_lang.UTF-8');
    $output = strftime(date($CONFIG["date_format"], $value));
```

But it has no effect, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed `$output = strftime("%a %h %d %Y %H:%M", $value);`